# WordPress delete_option(); Wildcard capability?

Tags: php, wordpress, wildcard, prefix

How would one go about deleting all option names in a WordPress database beginning with a specific prefix?

I would assume we need to specify a prefix, get all options that begin with that prefix, and then delete each option found.

Here is a sample of the prefix and WP functions for getting and deleting options in the database.

```
<?php
$prefix = 'cpt_';
$getOpt = get_option($prefix);
foreach($getOpt as $toDelete){
    $deleteOpt = delete_option($prefix);
    if(!$deleteOpt){
        echo 'Failure.';
    }
    if($deleteOpt){
        echo 'Success.';
    }
}
?>
```

**Resources:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a "whitelist" of all the variables your plugin sets (I assume you are looking at a plugin uninstall script), then just loop through it at the other end so you can delete them all.

Something as simple as:

```
// Somewhere in your plugin, maybe as a class property
$pluginDefinedOptions = array('my_name', 'my_created', 'my_modified'); // etc

// Clear up our settings
foreach($pluginDefinedOptions as $optionName) {
    delete_option($optionName);
}
```

This is the only way to keep your plugin code tidy.

Answer (score 9):

You could run this query:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE 'cpt_%'" );
```

or put it in a function like so:

```
function delete_options_prefixed( $prefix ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE '{$prefix}%'" );
}
delete_options_prefixed( 'cpt_' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "myplugin_" with your prefix:

```
global $wpdb;

$plugin_options = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_name FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE 'myplugin_%'" );

foreach( $plugin_options as $option ) {
    delete_option( $option->option_name );
}
```